# How to do below assignment of source and Process using jmeter script?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

[image: Logical Controller]

I Need to assign 1 source with 5 process and 1 Process with 5 sources using any controller jmeter

Answer (score 0):

If this is a static list you can use csv as input

Comment: Hi Rahul, Its not static list. It is sample list of source and process. i need to assign 1 source to 5 process and 1 process to 5 source. this need to be assign for 500 source list.

Comment: I assume this is part of test data preparation before running your load test. If so then you can have a csv file with 500 sources and the required combination of processes.

If your question is around - "given 50 processes and 500 sources, how to programmatically arrange processes at run time such that each source has 5 processes and 1 process is assigned to 5 sources" then it is more of a logic question. You can make use of JSR223 Pre Processor with groovy / java language.